# How to export Ansible Inventory name to Server as variable

Tags: ansible, ubuntu-18.04, ansible-inventory

I am trying to communicate the Ansible inventory name of a server to the server itself, so I can use that name in a script that changes the server's hostname to the same name. Sending it to a file, or an environment variable would work great.

For example, in my inventory (/etc/ansible/hosts) I have:

```
[servergroupexample]
host1 ansible_host=1.2.3.4
host2 ansible_host=5.6.7.8
```

And I'd like to somehow communicate to 1.2.3.4 that his name is "host1", and 5.6.7.8 that her name is "host2" so I can reference these names in a script and set their hostnames to host1/host2 respectively. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inventory_hostname` and `inventory_hostname_short` are part of the [special variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html) available to you.

For this specific case, I suggest you use `inventory_hostname_short` so the following example still works if you later decide to name your hosts after their full fqdn name (e.g. host3.mydomain.com)

If your goal is to configure your target hostname, you can use the following playbook which uses the [`hostname` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/hostname_module.html)

```
- name: Set hostname of my machines
  hosts: servergroupexample

  tasks:
    - name: Set hostname
      hostname:
        name: "{{ inventory_hostname_short }}"
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Code

```
- name: Loop through example servers and show the hostname, ansible_host attribute
  debug:
    msg: "ansible_host attribute of {{ item }} is {{ hostvars[item]['ansible_host'] }}"
  loop: "{{ groups['servergroupexample'] }}"
```

#### Result

```
ok: [localhost] => (item=host1) => {
    "msg": "ansible_host attribute of host1 is 1.2.3.4"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=host2) => {
    "msg": "ansible_host attribute of host2 is 5.6.7.8"
}
```

You can change the task from debug to shell or template, etc.

To output only the matching ansible_host:

```
- name: Loop through example servers and show the hostname, ansible_host attribute
  debug:
    msg: "ansible_host attribute of {{ item }} is {{ hostvars[item]['ansible_host'] }}"
  when: ansible_host == hostvars[item]['ansible_host']
  loop: "{{ groups['servergroupexample'] }}"
```